# Javascript Functions Only Run After Refresh (f5)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, refresh

Background: I bought a template for a wedding photography website I'm currently working on. I have an average knowledge base on html and css. Never really done javascript as most of my time I spend coding c#. You can see the website at

http://www.nm-photography.co.uk

A full working version of the website can be found here: http://themeforest.net/item/jphotolio-responsive-wedding-photography-template/full_screen_preview/3057579

The error: when you open the website, it works fine and pulls all the right images through javascript (jQuery(document)). However, if you go to another page, none of the javascript seems to load until you press ctrl r / f5. if you go back to the home page, this also then does not work unless you press refresh.

My research: So I've spent hours digging around Google, yes even page 2! Some people are using the on.load function, others some background worker functions? Again, I'm confident in c#, not javascript! I will paste the code below providing it's not too long! I'm not too sure where to put the right code so if anybody could help me out in the right direction, I would be most appreciative :) Thanks!

I have also noticed, in the java script, the right click has been disabled, however, once page has been refreshed to get images to load, you are then able to right click the page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jegbg.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{   

    resize_window("#jegbgcontainer");       

    /** bind jeg default **/
    $(window).jegdefault({
        curtain : 1,
        rightclick  : 0,
        clickmsg    : "Disable Right Mouse Click"
    });

    var content = [         
        { "index":0,
          "type":"image",
          "source":"images\/emr-1-3.jpg",
          "pos":"top",
          "title":"Image Slider",
          "link":"masonry.html#!/gordon-jennas-wedding",
          "desc":"<p><strong><\/strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<\/p>\n<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\n"},          
        {"index":1,
          "type":"image",
          "source":"images\/misc-1-3.jpg",
          "pos":"center",
          "title":"Slider to contact",
          "link":"contact.html",
          "desc":"<p><strong><\/strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<\/p>\n<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\n"},          
        {"index":2,
          "type":"image",
          "source":"images\/464713958_1d6a51c6c0_b1.jpg",
          "pos":"top",
          "title":"Slider to Password Page",
          "link":"masonry.html#!/flower-peda",
          "desc":"<p><strong><\/strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<\/p>\n<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\n"},                                  
        {"index":3,
          "type":"video",
          "source":{ "videotype":"youtube",
                     "src":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=w3jTxLs7Bek"},
          "title":"Slider with Video",
          "link":"masonry.html#!/just-married",
          "desc":"<p><strong><\/strong>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry&#8217;s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.<\/p>\n<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<\/p>\n"}                       
    ];

    var holddesc = undefined;

    var jegbg = $("#jegbgcontainer").jegbg({
        fade_speed                  : 700,
        delay                       : 10000,
        content                     : content,
        autostart                   : true,
        partial_load                : true
    },  function(ele, media){
        $('#homepita').fadeIn(1000);                
        $('#homepita .torapper').html(ele.title);       
        $(".homelink a").attr("href" , ele.link);
        holddesc = ele.desc;

        if(!$(".homeinfo").is(":visible")) {
            pitaSlideUp();
        }
    });

    /* binding touchwipe, disable this feature if using iphone */
    if(scw(iphonewidth)) {
        $(".texthome").touchwipe({
            wipeLeft: function(e) {                 
                jegbg.next();
                return false;
            },
            wipeRight: function() {                 
                jegbg.prev();
                return false;
            },
            min_move_x: 20,
            min_move_y: 20,
            preventDefaultEvents: true
        }); 
    }

    var pitaSlideUp = function(){
        jegbg.restart();
        $(".homeblock").slideUp("fast", function(){
            $("#homepita").animate({
                "right" : -288
            }, function(){
                $(".homeinfo").fadeIn("fast", function(){
                    $(this).attr("style","").addClass("displayblock");
                });
                $(".homeblock").removeClass("homedesc");
                $(".homedescdetail").remove();
            });
        });
    };

    $(window).resize(function(){pitaSlideUp();});

    var pitaSlideDown = function() {
        jegbg.pause();
        $("#homepita").addClass("hptoogle");
        $(".homeblockinside").prepend("<div class='homedescdetail'>" + holddesc + "</div>");
        $(".homeblock").slideDown("fast", function(){
            $(this).addClass("homedesc");
            $(".homedescdetail").css({
                height  : $('.homeblockinside').height() - 30,
                width   : $('.homeblockinside').width() - 12
            });
            jpanel = $(".homedescdetail").jScrollPane().data().jsp;             
        });
    };

    $(".homeinfo").click(function(){
        $(this).fadeOut("fast");
        $("#homepita").animate({
            "right" : -5
        }, function(){
            pitaSlideDown();
        });
    });

    $(".homeblock .closeme, .torapper").click(function(){
        pitaSlideUp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Try not to refer to 'JavaScript' as 'Java', it's confusing and makes JS people rage

Comment: I'm very sorry! I didn't know there was a difference :/

Comment: Are you sure you are including jquery correctly, as my chrome developer tools show `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` and no pictures are coming.

Comment: Try to use the Google CDN jquery `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Markus403 I tried this but it didn't work :/ The images wouldn't load at all then on the web page!

Comment: Ok that was a proxy problem on my side.. sry for the confusion. Looks like it is loading images but most of the images in your directory are just black or gray.

Answer (score 0):

well i use

```
$(function(){

    //executes after everything is loaded 

});
```

see if it helps mate

also make sure your jQuery references are correct, its possible that the jQUery link relative path goes wrong if you navigate from another page, but works fine if you refresh the same page

Comment: Tried this but this made the website worse! Really feel out of my depth here haha!

Comment: Well this is actually one of the correct and most common jQuery ways to do on load, so if this messed up your website, then something in your code is wrong... Ill have a look when im home. Just on phone now  :p

Comment: Okay thanks! I don't have a problem paying somebody to fix this, i don't want to imagine what a web dev would charge these days! I'm just getting more bookings for weddings and I really need a website up fast! This is the nicest theme I've seen and didn't hesitate to buy!

Comment: thats alright mate no need to explain, helping devs in need is what we are here for :)

Comment: did you try putting `alert("test")` or `console.write` after every function in your code to see where your code fails? also reduce your `jQuery(document).ready(function($)` to `$(function(){`, if it doesnt work you might need to download latest jQuery libraries and use them instead of yours, get them at ` http://jquery.com/ `

Comment: No, I didn't know I could do that! I'm assuming these work the same as tracers do in c#! Will give it a bash when I get home :)

Comment: well basically, javascript is a script language its not being compiled  but instead executes line by line, so you could fill it with alerts "test1" "test2" and see which one doesnt pop, your code fails somewhere before it reaches that alert.

Answer (score 0):

Move your script content out of the div with `id="jegbgcontainer"` as the content of this container is replaced thus replacing your script when another page is loaded.

Comment: I don't understand. The script content is placed on the html page after the div tags for jegbgcontainer have been closed?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem! The html files are being loaded but there are phtml files. These were not synced with the html hence the issue! Thanks for the help and  troubleshooting guys!